# nginx location with multiple subdirectories (django i18n)

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I got this server, where I use django i18n for a few languages, but I can't make nginx serve those directories using the same location thing.

```
location /(fr|en|ko|de)/ {
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8005;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    add_header P3P 'CP=ALL DSP COR PSAa PSDa OUR NOR ONL UNI COM NAV"';
}
```

But this doens't work and doesn't serve the request from those urls.

The only solution that seems to work is the one where i make 4 location block, but this can't be the best solution...

So, what is the real solution ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have confused the syntax for a prefix location and a regular expression location.

You need to specify a group of languages and therefore require a regular expression.

The correct expression is this:

```
location ~* ^/(fr|en|ko|de)/ { ... }
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.